# Two-dimensional array in Python (stupid problem)

Tags: python

It is so stupid. This code works

```
N = int(input("Input the N: "))

MATRIX = [0] * N
for i in range(N):
    MATRIX[i] = [0] * N
print(MATRIX)

print(" ")
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        z = int(input(" "))
        MATRIX[i][j] = z

print(MATRIX)
```

But if I change 11 line. Instead of `z = int(input(" "))`, if I write `z = int(input())` it will not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKV5K.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cexF4.png)

i tried nothing, it is just stupid

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Сырым\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    z = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have pressed the Enter key (without typing any integer value) when prompted for input, which means you have passed an empty string to the int() function.

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is the same error when we are trying to convert any string value to integer

Example - Converting character 'A' to integer

```
>>> int('A')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```